# URL rewriting: how to configure rules for new categories added

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am learning URL rewriting and found that we match the URL of incoming request and then rewrite the URL on the basis of match something like this:

```
if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Products/Books.aspx")) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Products.aspx?Category=Books");
    }
    else if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("/Products/DVDs.aspx")) {
        Context.RewritePath("/Products.aspx?Category=DVDs");
    }
```

Above Books and DVDs are categories. so here i am confused that if a user adds a mew category like Computer then what will happen or i have to regularly update the condition which i done think is good.

Comment: Please try editing question title to give meaningful name. ***New to URL rewriting*** doesn't seems like a question!!!

Answer (score 0):

User need to develop a logic to map the url to page like this.

suppose Url that contains product and category then redirect to product page with category in query string

```
product/book.aspx
product/dvd.aspx
product/newcategory.aspx
```

to

```
product.aspx?category=book
product.aspx?category=dvd
product.aspx?category=newcategory
```

means finally you need to redirect any category to

```
product.aspx?category=valueof category
```

below is the example of the rule in rewriting with iis.

```
<rule name="Rewrite to Product" enabled="true">
<match url="^http://mysite.co.uk/Product/[0-9a-z-]+/([0-9]+)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://mysite.co.uk/Product.aspx?Category={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

For more details you can visit [Url Rewriting IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

Comment: that is ok, but when admin adds a new category Computer through admin application then how above configuration will be added

Comment: you need not to add the configuration every time. You need to make conman rules for pages that will follow all the times.